# Why did so many places only had writing after being conquered by a major empire?

Tags: historiography, writing

I have been realizing that this is a recurring pattern in much of history. Many places only had their first written accounts after being conquered by a major empire. Much of Europe (such Spain, France, England, Switzerland) only had their first written accounts after the Roman conquest. Similarly, writing in America (except for Mesoamerica) only appeared with the arrival of the Europeans. And in Oceania, writing arrived together with the British colonizers. In a somewhat related way, the Slavs became literate after the arrival of the Eastern Roman (major empire!) missionaries Cyril and Methodius. What is the explanation for this pattern?

This video is useful to illustrate my point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUpJ4yVCNrI

Comment: Basically, you're asking: "Why do some places not have the same technologies as more technologically advanced places?" There's really nothing more to it than that. Some places developed it, some places didn't, and those that did, when they conquered those that didn't, brought it with them.

Comment: What is your definition of "written account"? My impession is that there were written account of England long before the Roman conquest, e.g. by [Pytheas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pytheas)

Comment: Probably because running a major empire practically requires writing? So if you don't have it, the "Empire" certainly does.

Answer (score 3):

In Central Asia the pattern is actually the other way round quite often: Literacy is acquired (and writing systems are developed) by the *conquerors*. See [Turkic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Turkic_script), Khitan ([small](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khitan_small_script) and [large](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khitan_large_script)), [Tangut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangut_script), or [Mongolian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_script).

The reason is that writing is a technology that, although easily transmittable, is much more useful to some societies than to others. Literacy is mainly useful for record-keeping (say in a bureaucracy or in complex trade arrangements) or for transmitting important religious texts. If a society has neither a bureaucracy, nor complex trading systems, nor a need to transmit religious texts, it will usually not need writing.